# Got "class not registered" when debug web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis, com

We have a simple asp.net web site which uses c++ COM library. Also we have interop for this library (from creator of dll). In our site we add reference to this interop and use a lot of classes.
When I publish web site to Local IIS all works well. But when I try to debug site or run it in IIS Express I got an error "class not registered" when create object of any COM classes from library.
Environment: Windows 2012 R2, .Net 4.6.2 (also tried to use older versions), VS 2015 (run as administrator), IIS 7.5.
It will be great to get help there because I don't have a lot of experience in web development and can't understand what's happening.

Comment: Sounds like a user rights issue

Comment: I run VS as administrator. What do you suggest? Impersonate to .. some account?

Answer (score 1):

After deployment regsvr32 has to be called to register COM dll.
It is not enough to copy interop dll, but additionally copy COM dll and call regsvr32 -i comdll.dll

You can also try to debug it on local IIS by attaching to process (Debug->Attach to Process, mark checkbox "Show processes from all users", w3wp.exe)

IIS Express and class not registered looks for me more as 32/64 bit issue.

Comment: Class is registered in system: I see it in registry and as I mentioned all works fine when site is published in Local IIS.

Comment: And when I created simple console app it doesn't work (falls with error "class not registered") in 32 and 64 mode. But it works in Local IIS (x64) and it makes me crazy :)